# Bootstrap-datetimepicker plugin opens a box that is staying under the accordion. How to make it visible on the top of the accordion?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use bootstrap-datetimepicker for bootstrap 4 but when i use it in accordion. it is not showing up all of its box . The box for selecting date is under the card body. I tried positioning but not succeeded. I don't know about how to fix it ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-YWzhKL2whUzgiheMoBFwW8CKV4qpHQAEuvilg9FAn5VJUDwKZZxkJNuGM4XkWuk94WCrrwslk8yWNGmY1EduTA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.39.0/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" integrity="sha512-3JRrEUwaCkFUBLK1N8HehwQgu8e23jTH4np5NHOmQOobuC4ROQxFwFgBLTnhcnQRMs84muMh0PnnwXlPq5MGjg==" crossorigin="anonymous"
  />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
        <h2 class="mb-0">
          <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
              Collapsible Group Item #1
            </button>
        </h2>
      </div>

      <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="container">
            <div style="position: relative" id="global-container">
              <div style="position: relative; z-index: 1" id="container-1">
                <div style="position: relative; z-index: 50" id="content-1">
                  <div class="input-group date datetimepicker" id="d1" data-target-input="nearest">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#d1" value="01.01.1992" />
                    <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#d1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                      <div class="input-group-text">
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div style="position: relative; z-index: 2" id="container-2">
                <div style="position: relative; z-index: 2" id="content-2">
                  <div class="input-group date datetimepicker" id="d2" data-target-input="nearest">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#d2" value="01.01.1992" />
                    <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#d2" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                      <div class="input-group-text">
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
          <h2 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                Collapsible Group Item #2
              </button>
          </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
          <div class="card-body">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
            on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
            raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
          <h2 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                Collapsible Group Item #3
              </button>
          </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="input-group date datetimepicker" id="d3" data-target-input="nearest">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#d3" value="01.01.1992" />
                    <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#d3" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                      <div class="input-group-text">
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.39.0/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js" integrity="sha512-k6/Bkb8Fxf/c1Tkyl39yJwcOZ1P4cRrJu77p83zJjN2Z55prbFHxPs9vN7q3l3+tSMGPDdoH51AEU8Vgo1cgAA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
        format: "DD.MM.YYYY",
        locale: "tr",
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

codepen : https://codepen.io/mhdikmen0/pen/dyzqJbr

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you've applied z-index values to the surrounding elements, but removing those seems to help.

Inline styles are rarely a good idea. I'd remove all those position rules, also.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
    format: "DD.MM.YYYY",
    locale: "tr"
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-YWzhKL2whUzgiheMoBFwW8CKV4qpHQAEuvilg9FAn5VJUDwKZZxkJNuGM4XkWuk94WCrrwslk8yWNGmY1EduTA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.39.0/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" integrity="sha512-3JRrEUwaCkFUBLK1N8HehwQgu8e23jTH4np5NHOmQOobuC4ROQxFwFgBLTnhcnQRMs84muMh0PnnwXlPq5MGjg==" crossorigin="anonymous"
  />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
        <h2 class="mb-0">
          <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
              Collapsible Group Item #1
            </button>
        </h2>
      </div>

      <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="container">
            <div style="position: relative" id="global-container">
              <div style="position: relative;" id="container-1">
                <div style="position: relative;" id="content-1">
                  <div class="input-group date datetimepicker" id="d1" data-target-input="nearest">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#d1" value="01.01.1992" />
                    <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#d1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                      <div class="input-group-text">
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div style="position: relative;" id="container-2">
                <div style="position: relative;" id="content-2">
                  <div class="input-group date datetimepicker" id="d2" data-target-input="nearest">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#d2" value="01.01.1992" />
                    <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#d2" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                      <div class="input-group-text">
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
          <h2 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                Collapsible Group Item #2
              </button>
          </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
          <div class="card-body">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
            on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
            raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
          <h2 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                Collapsible Group Item #3
              </button>
          </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="input-group date datetimepicker" id="d3" data-target-input="nearest">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#d3" value="01.01.1992" />
                    <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#d3" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                      <div class="input-group-text">
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.39.0/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js" integrity="sha512-k6/Bkb8Fxf/c1Tkyl39yJwcOZ1P4cRrJu77p83zJjN2Z55prbFHxPs9vN7q3l3+tSMGPDdoH51AEU8Vgo1cgAA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```